# Symfony 2 - submit one form from array of forms

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I feel like answer to this is obvious, but i'm missing it... I make an array of edit forms, and render it to the twig. Then, if one form is submitted i want to make edit into database. This is my code, but i have no idea how to get $editForm from request. This is part of my controller's code:

```
$users = $em->getRepository('MainBundle:list_base')->findAll();

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $editForms[] = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('edit_list_base_' . $user->getId(), FormType::class, $user)
                ->add('firstname', TextType::class)
                ->add('lastname', TextType::class)
                ->getForm()
                ->createView();
    }       

    // ???

    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
    }
```

I would be glad if you can give me any suggestion.

Comment: Your $editForm is an array, but symfony expects it to be a form. You cannot do it this way. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Regarding the "how to get the form from the request?" you have to create a real, proper form; during the first pass, your form will not be submitted, hence used to render a view showing it to the user; when the user submits it, your code will enter the `if ($form->isSubmitted)` and SF will automagically populate your `$form` with the values given by your user.

Comment: After submitting one of the edit forms in view i want to catch it this controller action and persist it into database.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough: what is your use case ? Do you have to show X forms, and whichever is submitted should be processed ? Do you have to show several forms or could just 1 be enough ? Do you have to iterate on all the forms ?

Comment: From the list of users i show only one edit form with name "edit_list_base_$userId", and after change i submit it. Other edit forms are hidden. I'm aware that i'm sending all edit forms, but that's okay, since theire placeholders are a current data, so no change is done.

Comment: Maybe submitting all forms is also a way. But i have no idea about performance of that way.

Comment: If you need only 1 form, output only one form. Could you not create a simple form based on your current form and add a new Entity form type that contains the selected user ?

Comment: Outputting one form makes me use slug, and i can't use it, because all forms need to be available in a single view without reloading. Using popup with iframe is also not an option.

Comment: An alternative might be to list users, each with an `Edit user` button.  That button then launches the edit form for that specific user.

Comment: You can use the request to find which  form was submitted(by the id), then handle the request in that form. But i think you should do this before creating the form view.